# Using OpenCV Face recognition algorithms in Android application

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to implement face recognition in an android app and after a bit of research i installed the opencv android library and imported it in the android application.

I also learned that the 3 most used algorithms (at least the most frequently used in tutorials) for face recognition are LBPH, FischerFaces and Eigenfaces, but i cannot find their implementations in the SDK, am i missing something?

Do i have to import C++ code via JNI? or are there some java implementations  i can use in android apps?

Comment: the api for the facerecognizers is in the sdk already, though there's some jni nessecary to supply the actual [create functions](http://answers.opencv.org/question/34342/missing-createfisherfacerecognizer-method-on/)

Comment: Hi @berak My question now is:, once i have the wrapper for createFisherFaceRecognizer() up and running and i am able to write facerec = new FisherFaceRecognizer(), will  i be able to call every method listed in the C++ FaceRecognizer api? what i am asking is, will it just work as the c++ code does?.
I am a bit puzzled because the java FaceRecognizer api seems different and not compatible with the c++ one. For example the train() method takes vector<Mat> and vector<Int> in C++  as parameters, but the java api wants List<Mat> and Mat. How am i supposed to manage labels with a Mat object?

Comment: made an answer since code in comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i made a quick (dummy) try, it should go similar to this:

```
    facerec = new createFisherFaceRecognizer(); 
    // traindata
    List<Mat> traindata = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    traindata.add(image1);    // add grayscale images, all cropped to the same size (like(90x90)
    traindata.add(image2);    // ...

    // trainlabels, i guess, MatOfInt(1,2,3) would work, too
    Mat labels = new Mat(1,traindata.size(), CvType.CV_32S);
    int [] l = {1,2,3, ... }; // 1 label for each image
    labels.put(0, 0, l);
    facerec.train( traindata, labels );

    // now to prediction:
    int [] label = new int[1];
    double [] conf = new double[1];
    // test_im must be grayscale, cropped to same size as the trainimages
    facerec.predict(test_im, label, conf); 
    System.out.println("rec " + label[0] + " " + conf[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the information i needed. Now i have to deal with some NDK/Android errors but it's not about opencv usage. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, thank for this answer. I implemented this code but I am always getting confidence as 0.0. Any suggestions for that.